# Los fragment están entrando dos veces al observer en Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Tengo un observador en cada fragmento y tengo el problema de que entra dos veces en el observador y no lo sé muy bien porque, veamos si me puede ayudar. Este es mi caso de uso:

```
class GetRegionsCasesUseCase {

    fun getRegionCases(casesRepositoryLiveDataContract: CasesRepositoryLiveDataContract) {
        object: AsyncTask<List<CasesModel>, Void, Void>(){
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: List<CasesModel>?): Void? {
                try {
                    val rows: List<List<String>> = csvReader().readAll(URL(CASES_FILE_URL).openStream())
                    val listCCAA: List<CasesModel> = rows.map {
                        CasesModel(it[0], it[1], it[2], it[3], it[4], it[5])
                    }
                    val lastDate: String = listCCAA.map { it.date }.last { it.isNotEmpty() }
                    val finalItems = listCCAA.filter { lastDate == it.date }
                    casesRepositoryLiveDataContract.onSuccess(finalItems)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                return null
            }
        }.execute()
    }
}
```

Este es mi repository:

```
class CasesFragmentRepository {

    @Inject
    lateinit var getRegionsCasesUseCase: GetRegionsCasesUseCase

    private val regionsCases = MutableLiveData<List<CasesModel>>()

    init {
        GlobalApplication.useCaseApplicationComponent?.inject(this)
    }

    fun getRegionsCasesListFromRepository(): LiveData<List<CasesModel>> {
        return regionsCases
    }

    fun getRegionsCasesListUseCase() {
        getRegionsCasesUseCase.getRegionCases(object : CasesRepositoryLiveDataContract {
            override fun showError(show: Boolean?) {

            }

            override fun onLoading(loading: Boolean) {

            }

            override fun onSuccess(regionsCasesList: List<CasesModel>?) {
                regionsCases.postValue(regionsCasesList)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Este es mi view model:

```
class CasesFragmentViewModel: ViewModel(), CasesFragmentContract {

    @Inject
    lateinit var casesFragmentRepository: CasesFragmentRepository

    init {
        GlobalApplication.viewModelApplicationComponent?.inject(this)
    }

    fun getCountriesFlagLiveData(): LiveData<List<CasesModel>> {
        casesFragmentRepository.getRegionsCasesListUseCase()
        return casesFragmentRepository.getRegionsCasesListFromRepository()
    }

    override fun getRegionsCasesFromFile() {
        casesFragmentRepository.getRegionsCasesListFromRepository()
    }
}
```

Y finalmente, este es mi fragment:

```
class CasesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var casesFragmentViewModel: CasesFragmentViewModel

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): CasesFragment {
            return CasesFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cases, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        casesFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CasesFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        casesFragmentViewModel.getCountriesFlagLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Toast.makeText(context, it[0].casos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }
}
```

Añadí un Toast para ver si me mostraba los datos y lo hace, pero me muestra el Toast dos veces seguidas. No tengo ni idea de por qué podría estar pasando esto.

Comment: Por ir descartando, has probado en el fragment a descartar que el dato recibido no sea null? -> data?.let {Toast(data.first())} . Comprueba también que el método getCountriesFlagLiveData devuelva sólo un LiveData.

Comment: Comprueba también que el fragment se está creando sólo una vez, la arquitectura no está bien implementada, afectando al flujo y hay que descartar la posiblidad de que se esté llamando dos veces a newInstance